# Check if pattern exists in a keys of hash

Tags: regex, perl, perl-hash

I have a hash of following pattern

```
my %hash_table(
     23                => someintegertype,
     type              => somestringtype,
     12_someidentifier => someveryproblematictype
);
```

How do I check if pattern that `12_someidentifier` key follows exists in the hash or not? If so, I need to know the value in the form of `true` or `false`.

::UPDATE::
I wanted to check if the regex or pattern such as  `{[\d]_[\w+]}` exists or not?

Comment: You're missing an `=` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exists` tells you if a key exists. `$hash{$key}` gives you the value, so you can test it.

If you're looking to test multiple values against a regex (such as they keys of a hash) then the tool for the job is `grep`;

```
my @matches = grep { /\d+_\w+/ } keys %hash_table;
print @matches;
```

Whilst we're at it - turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. It'll help in the long run.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: OK. You're looking for matches in your keys - the tool for the job is `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this:

```
if (exists $hash_table{$12_someidentifier})
{
        print $12_someidentifier, "\n";
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Your pattern is the key, and in Perl above is the way to check key exists in a hash or not.

Comment: The above solution will cause vivification.  May not matter, but generally isn't a great idea when dealing with hashes.